# Determine version of IndexedDB supported by browser

Tags: indexeddb

Is there a way to determine the version of IndexDB that a browser supports? I understand that version 2.0 is available but that doesn't tell me what version is actually supported by the browser. Looking for a javascript solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use feature detection, e.g.

```
if ('getAll' in IDBObjectStore.prototype) {
  // you can use getAll
} else {
  // nope
}
```

or:

```
try {
  indexedDB.cmp(new UInt8Array([]), 0);
  // you can use binary keys
} catch (e) {
  // nope
}
```

Versioning is for specs; browsers roll out features incrementally.